# Qu'outrance « ne fut plus borné à une locution adverbiale » (Littré) : qu'en est-il ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, littérature, dictionnaires, substantivation, locutions

> Il serait à désirer que ce mot, qui est d'une grande force, ne fut
>   plus borné à une locution adverbiale, et rentrât dans l'emploi de tout
>   substantif. Pourquoi ne dirait-on pas l'outrance de son orgueil, de
>   ses prétentions, comme a fait Ronsard ?
>
> ---
>
> *L'impudente esperance / De ton sot appareil / 
>   Perira par l'outrance / D'un grand roy sans pareil,* (Ronsard, [*Les
>   Odes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=779dAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA252&dq=L'impudente%20esperance%20De%20ton%20sot%20appareil&pg=PA252#v=onepage&q=L'impudente%20esperance%20De%20ton%20sot%20appareil&f=false), [1550-1552](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_de_Ronsard#Les_Odes_(1550-1552)))
>
> ---
>
> Supplément au dictionnaire
>  Voici un emploi d'outrance hors de la
>   locution à outrance.
>  *Les défauts par saillie et comme qui dirait
>   les outrances de Corneille*, (Sainte-Beuve, [*Port-Royal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ey5LAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22%22Les%20d%C3%A9fauts%20par%20saillie%20et%20comme%20qui%20dirait%20les%20outrances%20de%20Corneille%22%22&pg=PA241#v=snippet&q=outrances%20de%20Corneille&f=false), [paru](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port-Royal_(Sainte-Beuve))
>   1840-1859)
>  Ces essais de rendre la liberté à un mot confiné
>   méritent d'être encouragés.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire de la langue française* (le Littré), [Émile Littré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Littr%C3%A9),
>   remarque etc. à [*outrance*](https://www.littre.org/definition/outrance), altérée ]

L'ont-ils été et ont-ils porté fruit ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outrance%20-%20%28%C3%A0%20outrance%29%20-%20%28%C3%A0%20toute%20outrance%29%2C%C3%A0%20outrance%2Coutrance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutrance%20-%20%28%C3%A0%20outrance%29%20-%20%28%C3%A0%20toute%20outrance%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20outrance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutrance%3B%2Cc0) ?) ; ce cas est-il unique ?

- Le mot [*outrance*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/outrance) fait l'objet d'emplois plus récents en substantif au *TLFi* (chez Feuillet, Courteline, France, Hourticq, Camus), qu'en est-il au 21<sup>e</sup> siècle ; qu'en est-il plus généralement ailleurs ; sait-on pourquoi on trouvait ce mot « d'une grande force » et peut-on expliquer pourquoi on pourrait ou non dire que le souhait de M. Littré s'est réalisé ?
- Trois siècles séparent Ronsard de Sainte-Beuve ; quel terme unique, synonyme plus usuel ou courant, s'est imposé plus généralement ; quelle nuance exprimerait l'*outrance* le cas échéant ?
- Même si l'on peut constater une « concurrence » de certaines formes, *beaucoup* de substantifs qui s'emploient en locution adverbiale ne disposent pas d'un usage autonome (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goose, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §965, 966), a fortiori postérieur comme avec *à outrance* ; est-ce un cas unique, y a-t-il un autre substantif dont le développement serait similaire ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En 1844, avant la publication du dictionnaire de Littré, Balzac écrivait dans *[Un prince de la bohème](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6116491s/f115.item.r=%22les%20outrances%22.zoom)*, mais en italicisant :

> Ce n'est pas la race *des doux*, j'incline à conclure pour un peu de débauche et plus que je n'en voudrais chez des natures brillantes et généreuses; mais c'est galant dans le genre de Richelieu, folâtre et peut-être trop dans la drôlerie; c'est peut-être ***les outrances*** du dix-huitième siècle; cela rejoint en arrière les mousquetaires, et cela fait tort à Champcenetz; mais *ce volage* tient aux arabesques et aux enjolivements de la vieille cour des Valois.

On remarquera d’autres italicisations *(des doux, ce volage)*. Pourquoi *« les outrances »* le fût-il aussi. Balzac sentait-il qu’il se permettait une liberté que d’aucuns désapprouveraient ? Ou voulait-il d’une manière ou d’une autre lier ces trois expressions en italiques ?

Cet exemple ne propose néanmoins pas une grande diminution de la période de trois siècles mentionnée dans la question, au mieux une petite vingtaine d’années. Intéressant néanmoins car elle survient à la fin de la période...

Il importe aussi de mentionner que Balzac était un grand amateur d’anciens usages linguistiques, on en trouve la trace ici et là dans ses écrits, et on s’en convaincrait de toute manière simplement par ses fabuleux *[Contes drôlatiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Cent_Contes_drolatiques)*. Son utilisation ici pourrait avoir été purement stylistique, volontairement archaïque.

---

Une autre trouvaille intéressante, *[L’Ordre des Bannerets et leur origine](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54251116/f15.image.r=%22outrances%22?rk=193134;0)*, « [*translaté*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/translater) sur le latin, et depuis mis en rimes françoises », copie « scupuleuse » publiée en 1827 d’une édition antérieure, en français elle aussi, de 1672. L’original en latin n’avait pas été retrouvé pour cette édition, et n’a peut-être toujours pas été localisé à ce jour... On y lit :

> Pourtant Normands Danois en Bretagne raudoient,
>   Et sans les Bandes plus molestée l'auroient ;
>   Car Neomenus mort, on n'y vit plus que transes,
>   Que deprisations, embusches et **outrances**.

Ceci nous offre donc une attestation datant possiblement de 1672, soit 120 ans après celle de Ronsard, et dans une position presque médiane entre ce dernier et Balzac cité ci-dessus, ou Sainte-Beuve mentionné dans la question.

Il demeure néanmoins possible que la *translation* du latin ait été antérieure à l’édition de 1672 utilisée pour celle de 1827...

---

En remplacement de ce terme, on pourrait penser à la liste de ses synonymes et prendre celui qui nous semble le mieux adapté, mais il y a des limitations à l'efficacité de cette technique, limitations auxquelles je me suis immédiatement buté.

En effet, je percevais ***démesure*** comme le plus apte à remplacer *outrance*, mais *Le Petit Robert* m'a rapidement remis à ma place, spécifiant une rareté d'utilisation au cours de son histoire entre environ 1660 et le début du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, ce qui recouvre une partie substantielle de la période d’éclipse du terme *outrance* mentionnée dans la question.

Qui plus est, il se pourrait bien que Littré en personne soit la cause de la remise en valeur de ce synonyme. En effet, on peut lire en son dictionnaire :

> [**DÉMESURE**](https://www.littre.org/definition/d%C3%A9mesure)
>   *Mot tombé en désuétude, mais qui est excellent, et qu'on pourrait rétablir à l'aide de démesuré.*

Se pourrait-il donc, me demandé-je abasourdi, que Littré se soit insurgé contre la mesure et la réflexion sobre et posée qui peut-être sclérosait son époque, et ait tenté d’y remédier en remettant à la mode des termes plus forts, plus extrêmes ? On pourrait du moins se pencher sur la question. Peut-être n’est-ce qu’un hasard. Peut-être que la quantité de mots qu’il a réussi à réinjecter dans la langue constitue-t-elle en soi un monde que l’on effleure seulement ici. La coïncidence est néanmoins, pour l’instant du moins, fascinante à mes yeux.

---

Les attestations du substantif *outrance* ont par ailleurs bien augmenté depuis Littré : presque immédiatement après sa remarque, on observe de grands écrivains incorporer le terme à leur prose, Théophile Gautier, Charles Baudelaire, Sainte-Beuve. Dans les décennies qui suivent, il y a Émile Zola, et le XX<sup>e</sup> nous en montre plusieurs exemples. Pourquoi, entre tous ces mots dont d’aucuns<sup>1</sup> expriment qu’ils aimeraient voir la (re)naissance, celui-ci en particulier a-t-il réussi ?

Je crois qu’avec la famille de mots qui incluent ce préfixe *outr- (outre, outrage, outrecuidance, outré, outrepasser, etc.)*, en plus de la locution adverbiale *à outrances*, qui n’avait pas cessé d’exister, le mot se comprenait aisément de la plupart des gens. Si aujourd’hui encore il n’est guère présent dans la langue, il s’y loge néanmoins avec aisance si l’on désire y recourir. On pourrait selon moi dire que Littré a réussi son pari de le ressusciter.

---

<sup>1</sup> ***Aucuns*** (au pluriel) serait un autre exemple de terme dont l’usage se limite aux cas où un autre mot l’introduit *(d’)*. Correspond-il cependant à votre question ?

Comment: La possibilité que Littré et son dictionnaire aient influencé l'usage, on aime bien l'idée. ;-) Dans tous les cas c'est une belle réponse ! Merci encore !